# Proof: Does $\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty $ implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty }f(x)-x=\infty $?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

The question is: does $\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty $ implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty }f(x)-x=\infty $ ?

I answered yes, and here is my proof.
If $\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty $ it means by definition that:
$\forall M+1, \exists x_0\in \mathbb{R} s.t. \forall x>x_0 \Rightarrow \frac{f(x)}{x}>M+1$
Now i can write by taking the same $M$ and $x_0$ that in the definition above and $\forall x>1$
$\forall M\in \mathbb{R}, \exists x_0\in \mathbb{R} s.t. \forall x>x_0 \Rightarrow f(x)-x>\frac{f(x)-x}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}-1>M+1-1=M$ Q.E.D.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly, I think you should improve your writing style. Example:
We need to show that for any $M>0$ there exists $x_0$ such that for $x>x_0$ we have $f(x)-x>M$.

Then, since $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to +\infty$, there exists $x_1$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{x}>M+1$. Taking $x_0=max\{x_1,1\}$ we have, for $x>x_0$
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}>M+1
$$
$$
f(x)>Mx+x
$$
and then
$$
f(x)-x>Mx>M
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. :-)

Comment: Alternatively, $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)-x)&=x\left(\frac {f(x)}{x}-1\right)\\
&=+\infty.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think your proof is written in a bit of a confusing way with the quantifications put in such a way that it makes the proof hard to read. Your proof (or at least the idea) does seem correct though, so nicely done. If you're allowed to use some properties of limits and not just the definition, then an alternative approach would just be to notice that

$$f(x)-x=\underbrace{x}_{\to\infty}\underbrace{\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}-1\right)}_{\to\infty}\to\infty$$

as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thk a lot for your answer. I think that we have to prove if via the definition but i am not sure about it.